# Creating gpkg with many layers using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I am trying to merge many shapefiles into a single gpkg using ogr2ogr (*version 3.0.2*).

The command I am using is:

```
ogr2ogr dst.gpkg src.shp -nln layerOne
ogr2ogr dst.gpkg src.shp -nln layerTwo
```

BUT when I run ogrinfo it says my `dst.gpkg` has only `layerTwo`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are overwriting `dst.gpkg` every time you run `ogr2ogr`.  From the geopackage [documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html?highlight=geopackage):

> For adding new layers into existing geopackage run ogr2ogr with **-update**.

So do:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG dst.gpkg src.shp -nln layerOne
ogr2ogr -f GPKG -update dst.gpkg src.shp -nln layerTwo
```

Or if all source shapefiles are in a single directory:

> Translation of a directory of shapefiles into a GeoPackage. Each file
>   will end up as a new table within the GPKG file. The file
>   filename.gpkg must not already exist, as it will be created.
>
> ```
>     ogr2ogr -f GPKG filename.gpkg /path/to/dir
> ```