# Batch importing shapefiles to geopackage as separate layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I have ~60 shp files with biological data (1 per species) and it would be useful to be able to have these in a single geopackage.

I can export them individually and set the layer to the species name but is there a way to import multiple shp files to a gpkg and keep the layer name to the shp file name i.e. the species?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: "if all source shapefiles are in a single directory:": https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347230/creating-gpkg-with-many-layers-using-ogr2ogr

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Package layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#package-layers) tool and then, select the **Add File(s)...** or **Add Directory...** option. If you use one of this options you don't need to load all the layers to the project.

[image: Package layers]